# Hibernate ignoring eager loading

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have a class `User` with the following field `rooms`

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=Room.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="room_users",
            joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="room_id") })
@JsonIgnore
private List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
```

at some point, I want to check if the user is in a room, like this

```
public ResponseEntity<?> joinRoom(@PathVariable Integer uid, @RequestHeader("Auth-Token") String token){
    try{
        User user = findByBackendToken(token, userRepository);
        Room room = roomRepository.findByUid(uid);

        if(user.getRooms().contains(room)){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED);
        } else {
            roomService.joinRoom(user, room);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(exception(e), HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }
}
```

but I'm seeing `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.inkdrop.app.domain.models.User.rooms, could not initialize proxy - no Session` on the line `user.getRooms().contains`

Seems like Hibernate is ignoring the `Eager`. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you calling the `getRooms` within a transactional session?

Comment: no...I guess I should, right? But the question is why, even if the `eager`, Hibernate isn't loading the rooms. Is this expected?

Comment: Indeed. That should cause hibernate to do the additional query for the rooms.

Comment: I would guess it is something to do about hibernate proxies, but I am not versed enough to give you a correct/complete answer to that question.

Comment: Can you show how you're querying the `User` inside your method `findByBackendToken` ?